# Is there a VSCODE equivalent for the Vi 'z' command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the Vi editor, one can issue a 'z' command to relocate the current line at the top of the page. I cannot yet see a similar option available in VSCODE.

Does anyone know if such an option is available in VSCODE, please?

NOTE: I have taken note of the Vim extensions, but I am not looking for a solution based upon installing an extension. Thanks.

Comment: I tried `zz` and it works in vscode.

Comment: @seuling - I don't see how that can not simply enter "zz" into the code. How are you going about that please?  I don't have a Vim extension installed.

Comment: Are you open to a macro solution?  And when you say "top of the page" do you mean top of the file or just the current editor viewport?

Comment: @BasilBear Sorry I figured out I already installed vim extension. But after disabled vim extension, I can use 'zz' command too. You can't use zz command in normal mode?

Comment: @seuling It's not "ZZ" (save and close) that I am looking for, it's "z" (reposition current line to top of page)

Comment: @BasilBear I mean "zz" for reposition cursor to current line. It works for my vscode anyway. I think there's some key mapping configuration cause I can use 'z' command without the extension

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this VIM extension for Vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) which may contain what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but I indicated that I am not looking for an extension-based solution. :)

Comment: Oh okay, I did not see that. Is there a reason why not ? The plugin seems to be very powerful

Comment: Simply because I don't want to "risk" any other affects on the IDE, for the sake of one desired feature.

Comment: Honestly, your text editor won't be affected in any other way, if you tune properly your plugin